# How to redirect new WordPress multisite user inside their admin panel after they log in?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, redirect

Here is the code in my functions.php that redirects users (to their new "Sample Page") when they log in:

```
function admin_default_page() {  
  return '/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

The problem is that the url to which we redirect is missing the users site url. 
For example, if a user creates a site "Bobs Trucks", it redirects them to

example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit (does not work)

instead of

example.com/bobstrucks/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit

I've tried all the WordPress functions to get the full url needed (example.com/bobstrucs/url-to-redirect-to) but have not succeeded.

I'm trying a rather hackish solution where I get the user ID form the logged in user, and get all the blogs the user has (= just one, "Bobs Trucks"):

```
function admin_default_page() {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $current_user->ID);
    foreach($blogs as $blog) { $userblog = $blog->siteurl; }
    return $userblog .'/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit';
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'admin_default_page');
```

But this one has the problem of not working the first time user logs in.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its an array with an object inside it. Quick question, whats the user id in that example?

Comment: echo $current_user->ID; ends up as "37". Was this what you meant?
How can I access the ["siteurl"] (key..?) of this object inside the array?

Comment: You could use a `foreach($blogs as $blog) { $userblog = $blog->siteurl; }` then check if `$userblog` is correct.

Comment: im sure theres a better alternative than looping but that should work for now provided the user only ever has one blog. Will find something when i can get to the computer :-)

Comment: Ok. Although the loop-solution was correct here seems to be a problem not knowing the necessary information early enough. Since the function gets triggered when user clicks "log in" apparently we don't know the $userblog etc. When user is logged in, the function works but not on the firts time when users loggs in.

Comment: could you update your question with said code please

Comment: This can be a bit funky because the entry point to the login can vary greatly... What URL are the users login from? Is there any `?redirect_to=ANOTHER-URL` in it? . . . . Your filter is missing some parameters that will be useful: `add_filter( 'login_redirect', function( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ){ return $redirect_to; }, 10, 3 );`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function admin_default_page() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() ) {
        $blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
        $blog = get_blog_details( array( 'blog_id' => $blog_id ) );
        $location = '/' . $blog->blogname . '/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit';
        wp_redirect( $location );
        exit;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'admin_default_page' );
```

Refs:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_details
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect

Comment: Unofurtunately this redirects users to example.com/example/wp-admin, not example.com/site/wp-admin. Also seems to create a redirect loop when user signs out.

Comment: I've updated the code to fix the redirect loop. I'm not sure how this can redirect to example.com/example/wp-admin. Can you give the exact link it is redirecting to?

Comment: The first version redirects to http://example.dev/Example/wp-admin/post.php?post=2&action=edit. This new version doesn't seem to redirect new users when they log in. Probably because the is_user_logged_in() happens when user clicks "log in" so it might be too late for it to be recognized in this function?

Comment: I'm not sure where `/Example/` is coming from. That isn't anywhere in my code. Unless that is the blog name? And humm, maybe the user isn't authorised at the point of `login_redirect`. Try removing `is_user_logged_in() &&`